# TextBox/NumberBox Filtering WINUI3

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp, winui, winui-3

Is it possible to implement an TextBox/NumberBox that filters and only accepts numeric values in real time just like what a NumberBox normaly does but not just when the user completes the input and if so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The general approach would be to handle the `BeforeTextChanging` event:

```
private void TextBox_BeforeTextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewText))
        foreach (char c in e.NewText)
            if (!char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox BeforeTextChanging="TextBox_BeforeTextChanging" />
```

Comment: The property BeforeTextChanging doesn't exist.

Comment: I's not a property. It's an event and it does exist: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.beforetextchanging?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077

Comment: This works in WinUI3